# I want to return an integer from a sql query not "Resource id #7"?

Tags: php, sql

Just for now I am trying to output the value of the highest `j_id` row.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT max(`j_id` +1) FROM `journey`");
```

I'm also adding that 1 to `j_id` purposely.

It works fine within the phpmyadmin panel. But when I try to use it within any php script I get back resource id. I know that `mysql_query()` does not return an array, I've tried `mysql_fetch_array($result)` but that doesn't work.

Any help would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT max(j_id +1) FROM journey");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$max_id_plus_one = $row[0];
```

`$result` is not the value you want - it *contains* it.

Note that the mysql extension is deprecated - you should move to mysqli or DBO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT max(j_id +1) as max_id FROM journey");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$max_id_plus_one = $row['max_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT max(j_id +1) as mid FROM journey");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$max_id_plus_one = $row['mid'];
```

Answer (score -1):

See the [Numeric Arrays AND Associative Arrays](http://web.guru99.com/arrays/) portion.

I think,Your Confusion will be clear...

```
mysql_fetch_array = Associative Arrays
mysql_fetch_row   = Numeric Arrays
```

If you use `mysql_fetch_array` then see the column name from phpmyadmin, and get the data from array using that column name.

If you use `mysql_fetch_row` then get the data from `$row[0]`.